# Three JS — Get ground position directly in front of Camera

Tags: 3d, three.js, rotation, trigonometry

I have a Perspective Camera, looking down the Z axis. I want to find the X, Z position of the floor at a given distance (let say 100) in front (on the Y axis) of the camera.

The camera rotation order is 'YXZ', so the Y describes the yaw.

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.app.width / window.app.height, 1, 10000);
camera.rotation.order = "YXZ";
camera.position.z = 0;
camera.position.y = 50;
```

I'm trying to then calculate the XZ of the area directly in front of where the camera is looking:

```
const inFrontOfCamera = {
    x: camera.position.x + (Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * 100),
    z: camera.position.z + (Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * 100),
}
```

This is working when I'm looking in some directions, but not others. I feel like I'm very close, but having a gap in my understanding!

Any pointers and solutions much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster) and [Ray](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Ray).

```
var raycaster = new Raycaster();
raycaster.setFromCamera( new Vector2(), camera );
var inFrontOfCamera = new Vector3();
raycaster.ray.at( 100, inFrontOfCamera );
```

If you're looking for a point on a ground plane:

```
var ground = new Plane() //defaults to horizontal plane at y=0
raycaster.ray.at( raycaster.ray.distanceToPlane( ground ), inFrontOfCamera );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go. Just wondering about the performance of this, or if there's a way which just uses trig functions from the rotation and position values?

Comment: I would guess it's pretty insignificant compared to the rendering. `new Vector3( 0, 0, -100 ).applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld )` should also work?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue where I wanted to get the **floor object** which was underneath my camera, and my camera was watching something else.

See the schema below:

[image]

To retrieve the object, I simply defined a vector for the direction (0, -1, 0) to point to the ground (y-axis) and I used a raycaster using the camera position as the following:

```
var vect = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);    
raycaster.set(camera.position, vect);
```